# serving static files in django on pythonanywhere

Tags: django, deployment, production, pythonanywhere, django-staticfiles

hello guys i need your help, i followed all the steps to serve my static files for my django application, i ran the collectstatic command, and i can see my files in the static folder in the root directory but i cant access them

idk why for example i type **https://scheduling.pythonanywhere.com/static/assets/css/style.css** i get **Not Found The requested resource was not found on this server**., eventhough ik that my files are there

```
(venv) 12:25 ~/Scheduling (main)$ ls
Mappord  appOrd  manage.py  mydb.sqlite3  requirements.txt  static  vercel.json
```

Answer (score 0):

It directly means if you can't access those files how can pythonanywhere so you would need to grant your user or change permission of directory by using:

```
chmod -R 770 /path/to/your/static/folder
```

I hope this helps you...

Comment: hello i ran this command and here is the permissions
`(venv) 12:56 ~/Scheduling (main)$ ls -l
drwxrwxr-x 6 Scheduling registered_users   4096 Feb 24 11:47 Mappord
drwxrwxr-x 3 Scheduling registered_users   4096 Feb 24 11:27 appOrd
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Scheduling registered_users    662 Feb 24 11:17 manage.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Scheduling registered_users 135168 Feb 24 11:17 mydb.sqlite3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Scheduling registered_users    386 Feb 24 11:17 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x 6 Scheduling registered_users   4096 Feb 24 11:54 static`

Comment: did you run the command i gave? your static is working now. if my solution helped please give correct answer mark.

Comment: yes yes ur command helped me solve the problem, thank's Sir

Comment: Please give me green tick...